# session level collation_server does not work ..?

Tags: mysql

Setting **collation_server** value in session level does not work in MySQL ..?

```
set session collation_server='utf8_bin';
```

When created a table after setting the collation of the server..,

```
create table case_sensitive(name varchar(20), id int);
```

I expect the collation to of the column **name** to be in **utf8_bin**.
But the information schema details of the column are as follows., What am I doing wrong here ...?

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           TABLE_CATALOG: def
            TABLE_SCHEMA: db10004db
              TABLE_NAME: case_sensitive
             COLUMN_NAME: name
        ORDINAL_POSITION: 1
          COLUMN_DEFAULT: NULL
             IS_NULLABLE: YES
               DATA_TYPE: varchar
CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH: 20
  CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH: 60
       NUMERIC_PRECISION: NULL
           NUMERIC_SCALE: NULL
      DATETIME_PRECISION: NULL
      CHARACTER_SET_NAME: utf8
          COLLATION_NAME: utf8_general_ci
             COLUMN_TYPE: varchar(20)
              COLUMN_KEY: 
                   EXTRA: 
              PRIVILEGES: select,insert,update,references
          COLUMN_COMMENT: 
   GENERATION_EXPRESSION:
```

Comment: `collation_server` applies when the database (schema) is created. After the database is created you can alter the default collation, see [13.1.1 ALTER DATABASE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-database.html).

Comment: @wchiquito In my case, I need to have tables with different collation in the same database.

Comment: You must explicitly indicate the collation in each table.